# Is it expected that reactive performance are comparable to blocking in my use case

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

I'm currently writing a rest webservice with the following tech : quarkus, resteasy, jackson, kotlin, native with graalvm and dynamodb as database.

I changed from blocking to reactive using mutiny and run some performance test. there were no significative improvement performance wise (a few ms at best) and a little overhead on the cpu in reactive.

I can't upload the whole app but here's some code snippet :

Controller :

```
@POST
fun createCard(@Valid @NotNull cardCreationRequest: CardCreationRequest): Uni<Response> {

    return cardService.createCard(getCreationOrderFromCardCreationRequest(cardCreationRequest))
        .onItem().transform {
            when (it) {
                is CardService.CardCreationResult.Created -> {
                    Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                        .entity(
                            CardCreationResponse(
                                it.cardNumber,
                                CardCreationResponse.Status.values().find { value -> value.value == it.status.name }
                            )
                        )
                        .build()
                }
                is CardService.CardCreationResult.AlreadyCreated -> {
                    Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT)
                        .entity(
                            ViolationReport(
                                "",
                                Response.Status.CONFLICT,
                                listOf(ViolationReport.Violation(...))
                            )
                        )
                        .build()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Service :

```
fun createCard(creationOrder: CreationOrder): Uni<CardCreationResult> {
    return creationOrdersRepository.findByOrderId(creationOrder.orderId)
        .onItem().transformToUni {item ->
            if (item != null) {
                Uni.createFrom().item(CardCreationResult.AlreadyCreated)
            } else {
                val cardNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                Uni.createFrom()
                    .completionStage(
                        creationOrdersRepository.save(
                            creationOrder,
                            OffsetDateTime.now(),
                            OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(CREATION_ORDER_TTL_IN_DAYS)
                        )
                    )
                    .chain { _ -> Uni.createFrom().completionStage(
                            creationOrdersRepository.updateCardNumberAndStatus(
                                creationOrder.orderId,
                                cardNumber,
                                CreationOrderStatus.SEND_TO_PARTNER,
                                OffsetDateTime.now(),
                                OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(CREATION_ORDER_TTL_IN_DAYS)
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    .replaceWith(CardCreationResult.Created(cardNumber, CreationOrderStatus.SEND_TO_PARTNER))
            }
        }

}
```

The repository uses the async quarkus dynamodb client (https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html#_going_asynchronous), nothing really fancy, just simple read and write requests.

Is there something wrong with my code or is my use case not really fit for reactive ?

Comment: Some informations about the test i performed : Duration : 3 min, ramp up : 30 sec, peak throughput : ~270 transaction per seconds

Also, there was a useless call to the database in the reactive version, after removing it and rerunning the test, in reactive i get  a performance boost of :
6 ms (90 percentile)
15 ms (99 percentile)

Comment: First of all, writing a decent performance test is hard. If you're measuring "peak throughput", that's a good sign your performance test is flawed. Second, reactive architecture will not give you better response times (users will not get responses faster), but it should give you much better throughput (more users should be able to get responses in a timely manner).

Comment: Also, if you are using quarkus-resteasy-mutiny and not quarkus-resteasy-reactive, you will definitely not see an improvement.

Comment: @geoand I'm using quarkus-resteasy-reactive and all the quarkus reactive extension (jackson, rest-client).

Comment: @Ladicek I gave the peak throughput measure just to give an idea of how far i'm pushing the app, but indeed this is not a sophisticated performance test, just a benchmark to push the system and see how it react, but feel free to tell me how i can improve it. 
Although the test is simple, i did witness what you describe, response time are more constant in reactive.